# Нужно ли ставить запятую после "хотя"?

Tags: пунктуация

> Хотя(,) интересно, сможет ли она найти работу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Хотя интересно, сможет ли она найти работу.***

Запятая ставится в сложноподчиненном предложении с придаточным изъяснительным: предикативное наречие "интересно" – это сказуемое в главном предложении.

Частица ЛИ используется в качестве союза.

Хотя – присоединительный подчинительный союз. Значение уступки связано с предыдущим текстом.